# TypeError: field_errors.join is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, expressionengine, safecracker

I am having a small issue with my ajax success call.

In the success call I have the following:

```
if (data.success) {
                window.location.href = "/account/submission-complete/"+data.entry_id;
            } else {
                var field_errors = '';
                for (field in data.field_errors) {
                    field_errors += data.field_errors[field]+"\n";
                }       

                var formErrors = 'Upload Failed<br>' + data.errors.join('<br>') + field_errors.join('<br>');

                var percentVal = '0%';
                bar.width(percentVal)
                percent.html(percentVal);
                $('#file-info').html(formErrors).slideDown('slow');
            }
```

The following error is being output in my JS console...

> TypeError: field_errors.join is not a function

Can anyone explain to me why this is occuring, and how I can fix it? as I need to add a '
' after, which I only know how to use .join().

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
field_errors.join('<br>')
```

do this:

```
data.field_errors.join('<br/>')
```

Since `join` is used to join all elements of an array into a string. Hence, it works on the array elements, not string, which is your `field_errors` is here.

**UPDATE**

```
// Add all the object data into the field_errors array
var field_errors = [];
for (field in data.field_errors) {
    field_errors.push(data.field_errors[field]);
}

// Check the console, if the array is correct or not
console.log(field_errors);

// Now join will work on the array element
field_errors.join('<br/>')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, well it fixes the error, but stops the code working. I think this is because data.field_errors is a object... any ideas?

Comment: @ccdavies Ok, again `join` will not work on the objects. I have updated the code. Try it...